# inOrder Tree Traveral algorithm not working

Tags: javascript, data-structures

```
    class Node {
    constructor(data, left = null, right = null) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    };
};

class BST {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null
    };
    add(data) {
        const node = this.root;
        if (node === null) {
            this.root = new Node(data);
            return;
        } else {
            const searchTree = function(node) {
                if (data < node.data) {
                    if (node.left === null) {
                        node.left = new Node (data);
                        return;
                    } else if (node.left !== null) {
                        return searchTree(node.left);
                    }
                } else if (data > node.data) {
                    if (node.right === null) {
                        node.right = new Node(data);
                        return;
                    } else if (node.right !== null) {
                        return searchTree(node.right);
                    }
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            };
            return searchTree(node);
        };
    };

    findMin() {
        let current = this.root;
        while (current.left !== null) {
            current = current.left;
        }
        return current.data;
    }

    findMax() {
        let current = this.root;
        while (current.right !== null) {
            current = current.right;
        }
        return current.data;
    }
    find(data) {
        let current = this.root;
        while (current.data !== data) {
            if (data < current.data) {
                current = current.left; 
            } else {
                current = current.right;
            };
            if (current === null) {
                return null;
            };
        };
        return current;
    };

    isPresent(data) {
        let current = this.root;
        while (current.data !== data) {
            if (data < current.data) {
                current = current.left;
            } else {
                current = current.right;
            };
            if (current === null) {
                return false;
            };
        };
        return true;
    };

    remove(data) {
        const removeNode = function (node, data) {
            if (node == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (data == node.data) {
                // node has no children
                if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                // node has no left child
                if (node.left == null) {
                    return node.right;
                }
                // node has no right child
                if (node.right == null) {
                    return node.left;
                }
                // node has two children
                var tempNode = node.right;
                while (tempNode.left !== null) {
                    tempNode = tempNode.left
                }
                node.data = tempNode.data
                node.right = removeNode(node.right, tempNode.data)
                return node;
            } else if (data < node.data) {
                node.left = removeNode(node.left, data);
                return node;
            } else {
                node.right = removeNode(node.right, data);
                return node;
            };
        };
        this.root = removeNode(this.root, data);
    };

    findMinHeight(node = this.root) {
        if (node == null) {
            return -1;
        };
        let left = this.findMinHeight(node.left);
        let right = this.findMinHeight(node.right);
        if (left < right) {
            return left + 1;
        } else {
            return right + 1;
        };
    };

    findMaxHeight(node = this.root) {
        if (node == null) {
            return -1;
        };
        let left = this.findMinHeight(node.left);
        let right = this.findMinHeight(node.right);
        if (left > right) {
            return left + 1;
        } else {
            return right + 1;
        };
    };

    isBalanced() {
        return (this.findMaxHeight() >= this.findMaxHeight() - 1);
    }

    inOrder() {
        if (this.root == null){
            return null;
        } else {
            var result = new Array();
            function traverseInOrder(node) {
                node.left && traverseInOrder(node.left);
                result.push(node.data);
                node.right && traverseInOrder(node.right);
            }
            traverseInOrder(this.root);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

this is the output and the tree

```
var tree = new BST();
tree.add("10");
tree.add("19");
tree.add("17");
tree.add("21");
tree.add("5");
tree.add("1");
tree.add("6");
console.log(tree.inOrder())


 [
  '1',  '10', '17',
  '19', '21', '5',
  '6'
]
```

As you can see I've been digging and this is what everyone says to use but it just wont work, it goes down then over to the right it doesn't make any sense, here is a visualization of the tree. I have all the code here for testing if anyone wants to test it out it would be appreciated.

```
                             10
                           /    \
                         5       19
                       /  \     /  \
                      1    6   17   21
```

Comment: please add the complete code for testing.

Comment: @NinaScholz Added

Comment: "In a binary search tree, in-order traversal retrieves the keys in ascending sorted order."

Answer (score 3):

Your BST `add` and `inOrder` methods are correct, and the output is as should be expected, but you seem to expect a *numerical* order in your output. But since you have provided *string* values to your tree, the comparison is not numerical, but alphabetical. In that order, the output is correct. If you wanted numerical order, then pass *numbers* (without quotes):

```
var tree = new BST();
tree.add(10);
tree.add(19);
tree.add(17);
tree.add(21);
tree.add(5);
tree.add(1);
tree.add(6);
console.log(tree.inOrder())
```

If you run this, the output will be:

```
[ 1, 5, 6, 10, 17, 19, 21 ]
```

Comment: Any feedback on this answer, @Chase?